# Remove a bcache without erasing data

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, bcache

The question is simple (I think), I want to destroy my bcache setup, with is a 4tb hdd with a 16gb ssd as cache. I am wondering if I can safely remove the bcache and revert the two devices back to normal drives without losing any data. I do have another 4tb hard drive for backup just in case it does not work. I am pretty new to bcache and I am trying to move the platform to Unraid.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using wipefs to clear the signatures, then used testdisk to rewrite a table to the drive.